# Use a field as key and it must be unique for each record to use it to browse the table (Openerp)

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-view

Please in a view form I wish to use a field as key and it must be unique for each record to use it to browse the table in the other views , how to do it

```
    class saisirsoum(osv.osv):
        _name='saisir.soum' 

        _columns = {
        'NumOffre' : fields.char('N° Offre'), # to be defined as key !!
        'organisme_s' : fields.char('Organisme'),
        'des_offre' : fields.char('Designation'),
        'order_line' :fields.one2many('saisir.soumission.ligne','order_id','soumission_id'),
        'observation_d' : fields.text('Observation'),
    }
```

Comment: i really don't get your question...do you want to get the  unique id of a field (in a view) on submit and then use it to search ?

Comment: Yes exacte use NumOffre as key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you'll make `NumOffre` unique like this by setting the `_sql_constraints` variable. where you can also define a custom message to be shown when a user tries to add a duplicate entry.

```
class saisirsoum(osv.osv):

    _name='saisir.soum'

    _sql_constraints = [
    ('NumOffre', 'unique(NumOffre)', 'NumOffre already exists'),
    ]

    _columns = {
    'NumOffre' : fields.char('N° Offre'), # to be defined as key !!
    'organisme_s' : fields.char('Organisme'),
    'des_offre' : fields.char('Designation'),
    'order_line' :fields.one2many('saisir.soumission.ligne','order_id','soumission_id'),
    'observation_d' : fields.text('Observation'),
    }


    def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None): # when the record is about to created
        NumOffre = vals.get('NumOffre') #get NumOffre from the form
        if NumOffre:
            pass # you can do something with it e.g searching

        return super(saisirsoum, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context) # finally call the create method from the super class and create the record after you're done
```

You can also override the other CRUD methods like `write` and `unlink` in the same manner

Comment: i've edited my answer. make sure you don't already have duplicates of `NumOffre` in your database. if you have delete them and then upgrade the module and odoo should make your field unique

Comment: are you sure you don't have duplicate records already in the database...to be sure just create a new database and install your module and test again